# Submitted info not passing through

Tags: php, jquery

I've got 7*4 sets of input boxes. What I need is for only the sets that are filled out to pass through but ignore the rest. The input boxes are dynamically created for 4 different columns, and as such they should pass through only to the correct one. Each column represents a different array of information. They are named four, three, two, and one. The boxes that are created have incrementally increasing id numbers via _1 _2 --> _7.

```
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_friendly_1" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Friendly Name</span><br />
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_1" name="[<?php echo $catkey; ?>][]" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Actual Name</span><br />
```

The code I'm using which I'm sure I've screwed up is this (I have 4 copies of this for four_addone_, three_addone_ and so forth):

```
if ( $("id=[^four_addone_]").length ) 
{
    $("#^four_addone_").prop('name', 'four[' + $("#^four_addone_").length + '][]');
    $("#^four_addone_").prop('value', $("#^four_addone_friendly_").length );
} else {
    $("#^four_addone_").remove();
}
```

Problem is that nothing is getting passed through when I click my submit button and I'm not sure what to do. I didn't write this from scratch, was helped by a friend who is no longer available; I'm a newbie with jquery. My site is: http://icloudbackups.com/mmgen/

Any help to get this going would be very much appreciated.

Comment: how hard is it to ignore the empty ones on server side?

Comment: For someone that knows what they're doing, probably not very hard. For me, I'm clueless.

Comment: maybe you should ignore the fancy jquery and stick with the basics then

Comment: that, or someone can show me where i went wrong so i can learn it...

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrect, you have no name on the first input and your second input the name value is incorrect as it starts like [], try this.

```
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_friendly_1" name="friendly[<?php echo $catkey; ?>]" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Friendly Name</span><br />
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_1" name="actual[<?php echo $catkey; ?>][]" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Actual Name</span><br />
```

Comment: That still doesn't submit anything. It outputs a blank file.

Comment: so if you `print_r($_POST)` nothing is displayed? Also all of your checkboxes on that page need a value set

Comment: well my checkbox'd stuff all works fine. the only stuff not being passed through is the custom added ones.